# Laravel - Query not giving expected result

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this Query:

```
$identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('is_current', 1)->pluck('id');
$userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

    $my_query = DB::table('hr_employees AS e')
                ->leftJoin('appraisal_goals AS a', function($join) use ($identities)
                    {
                        $join->on('a.employee_id', '=', 'e.id')
                        ->where('a.appraisal_identity_id', '=', $identities)
                        ->where('a.is_visible', '=', 1)
                        ->where('a.is_special_project', '=', 0)                                    
                        ->whereNull('a.deleted_at');
                    })
                ->join('hr_departments AS d', function($join) use ($userCompany)
                    {
                        $join->on('e.department_id', '=', 'd.id')
                        ->where('d.company_id', '=', $userCompany);
                    })                        
                ->join('hr_work_locations AS l', function($join) use ($userCompany)
                    {
                        $join->on('l.id', '=', 'e.work_location_id')
                        ->where('l.company_id', '=', $userCompany);
                    })  
                ->join('hr_employee_types AS et', function($join) use ($userCompany)
                    {
                        $join->on('et.id', '=', 'e.employee_type_id')
                        ->where('et.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
            ->where('et.include_appraisal', '=', 1);
                    })                         
                ->leftJoin('hr_employees AS em', function($join) use ($userCompany)
                    {
                        $join->on('em.employee_code', '=', 'e.line_manager_id')
                        ->where('em.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                        ->where('em.hr_status', '=', '0');
                    }) 
                ->leftJoin('hr_employees AS emm', function($join) use ($userCompany)
                    {
                        $join->on('emm.employee_code', '=', 'em.line_manager_id')
                        ->where('emm.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                        ->where('emm.hr_status', '=', '0');
                    })                        
                ->leftJoin('hr_employees AS eh', function($join) use ($userCompany)
                    {
                        $join->on('eh.employee_code', '=', 'd.hr_business_partner_id')
                        ->where('eh.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                        ->where('eh.hr_status', '=', '0');
                    })    
                    ->where('e.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                    ->where('e.hr_status', '=', '0')
        ->whereIn('e.employee_code', [2, 3])
                ->select(
                        'e.employee_code',
                        DB::raw('CONCAT(e.first_name, " ", e.last_name) AS fullname'),
                        'e.email',
            DB::raw('(CASE WHEN a.is_approved = 0 THEN "DRAFT" WHEN a.is_approved = 1 THEN "AWAITING APPROVAL" WHEN a.is_approved = 2 THEN "NOT APPROVED" WHEN a.is_approved = 3 THEN "APPROVED" ELSE "NOT STARTED" END) AS is_approved'),
                        DB::raw('(CASE WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 0 THEN "DRAFT" WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 1 THEN "AWAITING APPROVAL" WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 2 THEN "NOT APPROVED" WHEN a.line_manager_mid_year_approved = 3 THEN "APPROVED" ELSE "NOT STARTED" END) AS line_manager_mid_year_approved'),
                        DB::raw('(CASE WHEN a.line_manager_year_end_approved = 0 THEN "DRAFT" WHEN a.line_manager_year_end_approved = 1 THEN "AWAITING APPROVAL" WHEN a.line_manager_year_end_approved = 2 THEN "NOT APPROVED" WHEN a.line_manager_year_end_approved = 3 THEN "APPROVED" ELSE "NOT STARTED" END) AS line_manager_year_end_approved'),
                        'd.dept_name',
                        'l.location_name',
                        'e.grade_level_name',
                        DB::raw('CONCAT(em.first_name, " ", em.last_name) AS manager'),
                        'em.email AS manager_email',
                        DB::raw('CONCAT(emm.first_name, " ", emm.last_name) AS manager_manager'),
                        DB::raw('CONCAT(eh.first_name, " ", eh.last_name) AS hrbp')
                       )
                ->distinct()
                ->get();
```

From the query above, I want to display all the employees, either the record matches or not. Then, compare the matching records.

The problem now is that whenever there is no matching record for work_location_id for any employee as in:

```
->join('hr_work_locations AS l', function($join) use ($userCompany)
   {
     $join->on('l.id', '=', 'e.work_location_id')
     ->where('l.company_id', '=', $userCompany);
   })
```

it won't add the employee detail into the list of the result. But I want all the employees either there is matching record or not.

How do I do it that whenever there is no matching record for work_location_id, it should just display "Not Specified" for work location instead of omitting the employee record?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a left join on `hr_work_locations` instead of inner join.

```
->leftJoin('hr_work_locations AS l', function($join) use ($userCompany)
   {
     $join->on('l.id', '=', 'e.work_location_id')
     ->where('l.company_id', '=', $userCompany);
   })
```

If you are using Mysql database then you can use [`coalesce`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) if location is null or missing record in locations table or you can handle it in your application level code

```
DB::raw('coalesce(l.location_name,"Not Specified") as location_name')
```

like

```
->select( //.. other columns
        'd.dept_name',
        DB::raw('coalesce(l.location_name,"Not Specified") as location_name'),
        'e.grade_level_name'
       )
```

Comment: Can you show me from the code how I can add this. Thanks

Comment: @mikefolu I have updated my answer please check